# Issue with sha1 sum of windows iso with brasero

Tags: dvd, brasero

i downloaded windows7 iso from digitalriver (official windows iso),the download was verified by sha1 fir integrity.no issue.

then i write to dvd using brasero software.

to check integrity of DVD , i copied it as image using brasero , copied image with filename UDFVolume.iso,then i checked sha1 of the image , but it doesnt match with sha1 of the downloaded iso.tried writing three dvds to make sure its not issue of DVD.

why this happened?

i tried the same method of copying my ubuntu cd as image and sha1 of it matches the downloaded iso

Answer (score 0):

The most common reason for such a checksum mismatch
is that optical media often return garbage after the
end of the payload data.
In this case, you will have to truncate the data
stream to the size of the original image.

For example (assumung that the drive has address /dev/sr0):

ls -l the_image.iso

Divide size by 2048

dd if=/dev/sr0 bs=2048 count=$divided_size | sha1sum